# Can you change preview code in Eclipse formatter

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to change the "preview" code used by the Eclipse formatter?

For example, the *Window->Preferences->Java-Code Style->Formatter->Indentation* tab shows the following preview code:

```
int[]   myArray     = {
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6           };
```

I would like to change it to:

```
int[]   myNewPreviewArray       = {
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16          };
```

I would like to add a few cases that are not handled in the default preview code.

Comment: You used to be able to in older versions of Eclipse but it's gone AWOL in Eclipse Luna. It was a button down below the preview window which allowed loading another file into the preview window. Highly useful, but gone.